# In Cakephp 3, Use another (not users but members) controller for login

Tags: authentication, model, controller, cakephp-3.0

I am using Cakephp 3 for building new application where user have to login for their account however I am hitting the login URL http://localserver.com/members/login and it redirects me to http://localserver.com/users/login

Look like the 'users' controller is set by default in Auth component. How can I override the default controller from 'users' to 'members'?

NOTE: The URLs are not LIVE as I am working on my local-server.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is related to the **userModel** config key, which defaults to **Users**.

Try this script in your controller’s beforeFilter() or initialize() methods.

```
// Pass settings in
$this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
    'Basic' => ['userModel' => 'Members'],
    'Form' => ['userModel' => 'Members']
]);
```

**Update:**
In addition to `userModel` to be worked properly you must set the `loginAction` too.

```
// Pass settings in
$this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
    'loginAction' => [
        'controller' => 'Members',
        'action' => 'login',
        'plugin' => false,     // or 'Members' if plugin
    ],
    'Basic' => ['userModel' => 'Members'],
    'Form' => ['userModel' => 'Members']
]);
```

[Cookbook 3.x Doc](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)

Comment: thanks @ndm you are right, I thought the loginAction's controller must comes from the model by default

Comment: in this case u can agree the answer ;)