# cakephp 2 redirect in the wrong place

Tags: authentication, cakephp-2.0

I am using Cakephp 2.8 for building new application where user have to login for their account however I am hitting the login URL https://xxx.fr/members/login and it redirects me to https://xxx.fr/users/login
Someone can help me ?
thank

P.s: i found this solution [In Cakephp 3, Use another (not users but members) controller for login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517726/in-cakephp-3-use-another-not-users-but-members-controller-for-login) but is not working for me.

Comment: Please share your authentication code. Because provided solution should have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mention "members" controller in Auth loginAction. Try to add following example code in AppController beforeFilter function -

```
 $this->Auth->loginAction = array(
        'controller' => 'members',
        'action' => 'login',
        'plugin' => false,
                'admin' => false
      );
```

OR mention "members" controller where component loads. Example -

```
public $components = array(
'Auth' => array(
    'loginAction' => array(
        'controller' => 'members',
        'action' => 'login',
        'plugin' => false
    ));
```

Hope above solution helps you.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks you ! it work now ! i am so happy, thank you again.